# cannot find the variables in php session

Tags: php

I want to use the php session to pass the username to the second page
but it shows error.

---

Notice: Undefined index: nam in D:\software 2\wamp\wamp\www\session\s2.php on line 5

---

my first page(s1.php) is like this

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
  session_start();     

?>

</head>
<body>
<p>hello</p>


<form method="get" action=" http://localhost/session/s2.php">
<input type="text" name="nam"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

my second page (s2.php) is bellow

```
<html>
   <head>
 <?php 
   session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['nam'];
?>
</head>
here is the second page
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: You never do `$_SESSION['nam'] = $_GET['nam']`, so your $_SESSION never gets populated.

Comment: nam will be in $_GET not $_SESSION

Answer (score 1):

Variables are not inserted into the session automatically. You need to insert them somehow. If you want to get the variables from the get paramaters posted by the form [$_GET](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is what you are looking for.

eg:

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
```

Have a look through [dealing with forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put session start at the top

```
<?php
  session_start();     

?> 
<html>
<head>
```

You're most likely not seeing the error that is generated.

Also, after the data is submitted, you won't have it in the SESSION yet, it will be in `$_GET['name']`

I would recommend that you set the `error_level` to `E_ALL` while working on your local machine

Comment: If you want to avoid "Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by ..."

Comment: Oh, when you said "You're most likely not seeing the error that is generated" I thought that you meant moving the session_start would reveal the error he was looking for that made his code not work; I see now

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, variables from a form are passed via GET or POST. In your case, you used

```
<form method="get" action=" http://localhost/session/s2.php">
```

So the type is GET (`method="get"`). To read GET variables, use _GET, not _SESSION. If you want POST variables, use _POST.

In your case, use `_GET['nam']` instead of `_SESSION['nam']`

Answer (score 0):

you should either :

add this line before echo $_SESSION['nam'];
$_GET['nam']=$_SESSION['nam'];

or 
echo $_GET['nam'];

Good Luck